# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'valor'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Não consigo encontar a razão dele dar AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'valor'

```
class DidaticaTech:
    def __int__(self, v=10, i=1):
        self.valor = v
        self.incremento = i
    def incrementa(self):
        self.valor = self.valor + self.incremento
a = DidaticaTech()
a.incremento()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-c86fe0605456> in <module>
----> 1 a.incrementa()

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'incrementa'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem dois erros no seu código. O primeiro erro, é que você está executando o método errado ao chamar `incremento` ao invés de `incrementa`.

O segundo erro, é que você criou o construtor com o nome errado. O nome deve ser `__init__` ao invés de `__int__`. Veja abaixo como deveria ficar seu código.

```
class DidaticaTech:

    def __init__(self, v = 10, i = 1):
        self.valor = v
        self.incremento = i

    def incrementa(self):
        self.valor = self.valor + self.incremento

a = DidaticaTech()
a.incrementa()
```

Answer (score 0):

Você se enganou a chamar a sua função.

A forma correta seria:

```
a = DidaticaTech()
a.incrementa()
```

A varíável `incremento` também está definida na sua classe e é um inteiro. Por isso é que o erro indica que essa variável é um inteiro e não tem nenhum atributo `incrementa`

Outro erro que você tem é na função `__init__`, você declarou como `__int__`